# How does digital pullups work?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pullup

I have lame question. How does digital pullups work? I'm asking because I don't understand DHT11 driver code. 
Sample code:

`bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, HIGH);
  usleep(500000);  // 500 ms
  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, LOW);
  usleep(20000);`

It will send start signal to DHT11, but it needs to be LOW for 500ms and then HIGH for 20us, but here signals are inverted. So, why how pullups works?
Schematic:
 [image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the right driver code?  I don't see the driver code you mention here:  https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library

Comment: In that code, they explicitly change the driver mode to Input when they are letting the pullup pull it high, and to Output when they want to override it.

Comment: @caveman This is arduino code. I need Raspberry Pi code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DHT11 is a humidity and temperature sensor using a single-wire communication between the microcontroller and the sensor.

[image]

In the diagram above, the 5K resistor is the pullup resistor, which is tied to Vdd (power supply)..  It keeps the DATA line in a high (1) condition in the absence of any signals from either end of the DATA line.

When the microcontroller wants to send data to the sensor, for a 0 it drives the line to ground (this is called "sinking"), and for 1, it just leaves the line into a high impedance mode, and lets the pullup resistor drive the line high.

Likewise, when the sensor sends data back to the microcontroller, the microcontroller will have the I/O line configured as a high-impedance input.  This allows the sensor to send data by pulsing the line low as needed for a 0.  It also doesn't drive the line high, but lets the resistor pull it up.

So the "normal" state for each of end of the DATA line is for both the microcontroller and the sensor to have their pins in a high-impedance state, and only drive the line to ground as needed to send to the other end.

Answer (score 1):

A pull-up is used to drive a signal to a high state, for example Vdd, when no driver capable of driving the signal high is available in the circuit/net/device that output the signal. An example of such output would be an open drain output.

The idea is to use a resistor between the signal and Vdd where the value of the resistor is weak enough so that the signal can be drawn towards the low state (GND in my example) when it is driven low by the output circuit. When the signal isn't driven low it is pulled up to its high state using the weak resistor. I tend to use resistor values of 10k or 47k.

The same reasoning is for pull-downs but there you want to drive the signal low using a weak resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more of the code.  The pullup is basically not active during the lines in the question because the gpio pin is set as an output.  But later, the pin is set to be an input. At that point, the pullup is creating a default state of 1.  But the sensor can and does pull it low to provide data back to the processor.

```
  // Set GPIO pin to output
  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);  <<----OUTPUT, so pullup doesn't really do anything.
  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);  // Why twice?  Probably just sloppy coding.

  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, HIGH);
  usleep(500000);  // 500 ms
  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, LOW);
  usleep(20000);

  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT); <<---- INPUT, pullup is significant now.

  data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

  // wait for pin to drop?
  while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == 1) {
    usleep(1);
  }

  // read data!
  for (int i=0; i< MAXTIMINGS; i++) {
    counter = 0;
    while ( bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == laststate) {
        counter++;
        //nanosleep(1);         // overclocking might change this?
        if (counter == 1000)
          break;
    }
```

As a side note, a quick read through this code shows it to be a bit more hacked together than the arduino sensor driver on their git tree.  If this doesn't work, it would probably make sense to rewrite by porting the arduino code over.